# ListView 2 items per row

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView, that like any other ListView, show one item each row.
[image]

I'm trying to make this ListView show 2 items each row, somethings like this:

[image]

I'm already using custom JSON Adapter to show listview results from JSON API.
My goal is to show an imageview each 1/2 row (each item).

Any ideas?

Comment: post your xml you tried

Comment: @TheUnrial an imageview each 1/2 row (each item) What do you mean by this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) with `numColumns` = 2

```
<GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:numColumns="2"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are actually talking about a `GridView` with `android:numColumns="2"` in the xml.

or

You can use,

```
gridview.setNumColumns(2);
```

programmatically.

[image]

The only challenge I see is (sort of but no) displaying the it like,

```
1 0

3 2

5 4

...
```

But you can handle that behavior in your adapter, if you want to know how, let me know.

Comment: I heard someone shouting: `"MODULO!"`. Didn't you?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein What did not get the joke?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you might want to look into is using a GridView instead of a ListView for this. You can explicitly set the number of columns to 2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
</GridView>
```